# OverLoading In python

Tags: python, overloading

```
class tri:
def __init__(self,x=0):
    self.x=x
def __str__(self):
    return '({0})'.format(self.x)
def __add__(self,one,two):
    length=self.x+one.x+two.x
    return length


>>>perp=tri(5)
>>>print(perp)
>>>base=tri(8)
>>>print(base)
>>>hyp=tri(9)
>>>print(hyp)
>>>print (perp+base+hyp)
```

This is showing me:

```
TypeError(): __add__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'two'
```

What's the problem?  I am not getting it.

Comment: The add method should only take two arguments; self, and the thing you're adding to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of overloading magic methods like `__add__` in python is to define custom functionality in your `__add__` method, but not to change it's basic purpose. The `__add__` method corresponds to the `+` operator, which is used as an operator between two variables. In other words `2 + 2` is basically saying `2.__add__(2)`. You defined your method as:

```
def __add__(self,one,two):
    length=self.x+one.x+two.x
    return length
```

So you're adding a third variable to the magic method therefore `2 + 2` is basically `2.__add__(2, missing_var)`, which is why it's telling you that a parameter is missing. I would recommend changing this definition to:

```
def __add__(self, one):
    return self.x + one.x
```

If you really want to overload your method, and then your `print` method will work as expected. If you really need a method to add three variables then define another method in the class, but overloading `__add__` typically isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 4):

[The signature of `__add__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) must be `__add__(self, other)`, not `__add__(self,one,two)`.  The left-hand argument to `+` is the `self` argument, and the right-hand argument is the other argument to `__add__`.

Comment: I guess the error message could be more clear. Instead of saying missing argument it could say you have an extra argument there.

Comment: what if we want to add lengths of three sides of triangle using __add__ function?

Comment: @ToobaAftab: It doesn't matter how many things you're adding together; each `+` in `a+b+c` only has two arguments.